# How many Verison of Shiva sahasranama is there?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, shiva, sahasranama, shiva-sahasranama

How many versions of shiva Sahasranama are there?

Comment: The following page gives 4 versions found in Mahabharata and various Puranas. (https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/articles/mahabharata.html) .. and if I am not wrong there are others which are found in the Tantras.

Comment: @Rickross thanks.btw do you know any acharya who has written commentary on Shiva Sahasranama?

Comment: Here is one -- https://archive.org/details/ionj_shiva-sahstranam-stotra-with-bhashya-of-shivendra-sarasvati-by-shrikrishna-pant-/page/n51/mode/2up

Comment: @Rickross aah sanskrit lol. anyways thanks 

Comment: Yes, that is a problem